# Can't install Picketlink Forge Plugin JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, picketlink, jboss-forge

I want to implement a simple form Login/Register feature in my application and unfortunately I only found tutorials which depend on the Picketlink plugin (if anybody knows tutorials for register/login, please tell me!). However, I installed the plugin:

```
forge install-plugin picketlink
```

and got this output:

```
Connecting to remote repository [https://raw.github.com/forge/plugin-repository/master/repository.yaml]... connected!
    ***INFO*** Preparing to install plugin: picketlink
    ***INFO*** Checking out plugin source files to [/var/folders/0d/s6yx2tks4lgf784zkv1ylnzm0000gn/T/forgetemp4633334032607758018] via 'git'
    ***INFO*** Switching to branch/tag [refs/heads/master]
```

But then it just stops there.
Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider [Forge 2](http://forge.jboss.org/download), as Forge 1 is no more developed actively?

After you install it and run it on the command line, you can install the picketlink addon (the new term for plugins if Forge 2) with the following command:

```
addon-install --coordinate org.picketlink.tools.forge:picketlink-forge-addon,1.0.0.Final
```

Cheers,
Ivan